# wp_insert_post_data filter not working correctly after upgrade to Wordpress 5

Tags: filters, save-post

I have the following code in a project.

```
function vb_post_modified_date_update($data, $postarr) {  
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )   
      return;  

    if (!empty($postarr['vb_modified_date_switch'])) {  
        $data['post_modified'] = $postarr['post_modified'];  
        $data['post_modified_gmt'] = $postarr['post_modified_gmt'];  
    }  

    return $data;  
}  

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'vb_post_modified_date_update', '99', 2 );
```

What this used to do (it worked before upgrading to Wordpress 5), is to keep the old value on `post_modified` and `post_modified_gmt` fields when saving the post and a checkbox (`vb_modified_date_switch`) is checked in the post editor.

According [documentation of `wp_insert_post_data`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data), `$data` should have the post data and `$postarr` should have the unmodified post data. However, debuging, I found that both variables have the same post data (modified data), so now I cant get the original `post_modified` and `post_modified_gmt`.

Is there any other way I can change the post data before is saved?

Thanks